# Is it possible to use ALSA or OSS on Windows?

Tags: windows, sound

Has nobody written a wrapper over DirectSound or something yet?

Comment: If you are looking for a portable audio API, check out PortAudio.

Answer (score 1):

ALSA and OSS, as far as I am aware, are not sound formats but rather audio platforms for Linux; a means of interacting with MIDI devices or sound cards.

As of this writing, I know of no ports or implementations of their APIs to the Windows platform. Both projects look relatively stale from a quick glance at their respective pages, so that doesn't seem surprising.